# Clarity of Flag 124-126 in the GSOD weather dataset

Tags: uses-of-open-data, weather, metadata

The following table provides information around the Flag 124-126 of the GSOD Weather dataset the [documentation of which is available here](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/gsod/GSOD_DESC.txt):

```
Flag    124-124   Char   A = 1 report of 6-hour precipitation 
                             amount.
                         B = Summation of 2 reports of 6-hour 
                             precipitation amount.
                         C = Summation of 3 reports of 6-hour 
                             precipitation amount.
                         D = Summation of 4 reports of 6-hour 
                             precipitation amount.
                         E = 1 report of 12-hour precipitation
                             amount.
                         F = Summation of 2 reports of 12-hour
                             precipitation amount.
                         G = 1 report of 24-hour precipitation
                             amount.
                         H = Station reported '0' as the amount
                             for the day (eg, from 6-hour reports),
                             but also reported at least one
                             occurrence of precipitation in hourly
                             observations--this could indicate a
                             trace occurred, but should be considered
                             as incomplete data for the day.
                         I = Station did not report any precip data
                             for the day and did not report any
                             occurrences of precipitation in its hourly
                             observations--it's still possible that
                             precip occurred but was not reported.
```

My question is around clarity of flags A to F which indicates precipitation amounts for periods shorter than 24 hours. For those flags must the precipitation amount be multiplied to reach a 24 hour period?

E.g. if the field = 0.10A (A = 1 report of 6-hour precipitation amount) is the total precipitation amount 0.10 * 4 = 0.40?

If not then what is the the purpose of noting that the amount reported is recorded for a 6 hour period?